# sdk/pageload-require is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk, pageload

I have SDK 1.13 and I want to use pageload API to give the alert message when html form is loaded in firefox browser. but I'm getting an error on console: require is not defined.
I have linked cfx file of add on SDK to file system directory:

```
ln -s PATH_TO_SDK/bin/cfx ~/bin/cfx
```

Still, I am not able to solve this error. Here is my code (Included in XUL file):

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
    pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.html",
    contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've installed the SDK and have run bin\activate within your extension before trying cfx run, right?

You can't run this stuff from an XUL file, which is why require... wont work. All of this needs to be in a main.js (in the lib folder). You'll need to communicate via the content script that you'll write (in the data folder). When the html loads (I'd add a window.listener or something from the content script) you'll use port.emit("loaded") or something similar and then you'll have to listen in the main.js with something like addon.port("loaded",somefunction). There's a lot of good documentation on this!

Comment: Can I use the SKD in a main.js even though my main application is in XUL?  I mean, can I combine the two?

Answer (score 0):

XUL files is quite an opposite of SDK modules. [SDK and XUL Comparison](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html).